# Input for CGAL classes from a file

Tags: c++, input, cgal

Is there an easy way to read points and segments in 2D, from the same file, using CGAL?

What should  be the format for this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CGAL `operator<<` is overloaded for kernel objects and streams. The format is, well, apparently undocumented but kind of obvious for simpler types.

```
#include <CGAL/basic.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;

int main()
{
  K::Point_2 p;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "2.05 3.05";

  ss >> p; // read from a stream
  std::cout << p << std::endl; // write to a stream

  K::Segment_2 s;
  ss.clear();
  ss << "2.3 4.2 4.2 2.3";
  ss >> s; // read a segment from a stream
  std::cout << s << std::endl; // write a segment to a stream
  return 0;
}
```

Looking at the code a `CGAL::Polygon_2` expects input like this:

```
"4 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0"
```

where the first number is the number of Points following and after that the points.

Comment: And is it possible to read a polygon from a file, and then get the segments that compose the polygon? Or should I read the file again to get the segments?

Comment: It remains unanswered if it's possible to read the segments and the points from the same file. X)

Comment: @MauricioZambon Well, that is entirely up to managing your input file. If you store some information about the amount of segments etc in it, this is trivial to implement.

Comment: When I said from the same file, I meant the same structure, no special treatment needed. :D But ok, I'll figure that out.

Comment: This answer misses the information about IO modes, since there is a way to customize the formatting.  The default "pretty" mode probably does not allow to write segments and read points because it adds a "Segment_2(...)" formatting.  See http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/IOstream/Chapter_main.html

Comment: @SylvainPion AFAIK, the default is `ASCII` mode.